wait_for asyncio event prevents aiohttp from proper cleanup
I found unintuitive behaviour of asincio.wait_for when waiting for asyncio.Event. Aiohttp cleanup is not working in this case:
import asyncio
import logging
from aiohttp import web

async def ctx(app):
   logging.info("ctx start")
   async def task():
       e = asyncio.Event()
       try:
           logging.info("Task started")
           await asyncio.wait_for(e.wait(), 10000)
       except asyncio.CancelledError:
           logging.info("Task received cancellation and exited cleanly")
       except asyncio.TimeoutError:
           logging.info("Task timeout occurred")
   t = asyncio.create_task(task())
   try:
       yield
   finally:
       logging.info("ctx ending")
       t.cancel()

if __name__ == "__main__":
   logging.basicConfig(
       level=logging.INFO,
       format="%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(levelname)s %(module)s - %(funcName)s: %(message)s",
       datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
       force=True,
   )
   app = web.Application()
   app.cleanup_ctx.extend([ctx])
   web.run_app(
       app,
       host="0.0.0.0",
       port=5000,
   )


I never see the ctx ending logline. However, if I change e.wait() to for example asyncio.sleep(100) inside wait_for, cleanup is working fine.
Can anyone please explain this behaviour?

looks like aiohttp issue.
the problem is reproduced with python=3.11.9 and aiohttp=3.9.3 running in docker. ugrading aiohttp to 3.11.10 solved the problem.
